# How to customize Acrylic brush

Tags: xaml, uwp, acrylic-material

I want to paint Stack Panel surface using Acrylic brush.

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicElementBrush}"></StackPanel>
```

It works for me but there is a problem when I want to change Tint color and opacity. There is a following code to change it:

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
    <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
        BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
        TintColor="#FFFF0000"
        TintOpacity="0.8"
        FallbackColor="#FF7F0000"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I don't know where should I place it and rename brush for this?

```
 <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource **MyAcrylicBrush**}"></StackPanel>
```

Thanks for help. 
P.S. You need Windows Insider SDK and system build 16190 or higher

Comment: Place it in `App.xaml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1:

Add `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` in `Application.Resources`

**In App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="#FFFF0000" TintOpacity="0.8" FallbackColor="#FF7F0000"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="#FFFF0000" TintOpacity="0.8" FallbackColor="#FFFF7F7F"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

### Method 2:

As @jsmyth886 answered

1. Add a separate [`ResourceDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary) file and place your `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` code

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
           <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="#FFFF0000" TintOpacity="0.8" FallbackColor="#FF7F0000"/>
       </ResourceDictionary>

       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}"/>
       </ResourceDictionary>

       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
           <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="#FFFF0000" TintOpacity="0.8" FallbackColor="#FFFF7F7F"/>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
   ```
2. You [`MergedDictionaries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary#Windows_UI_Xaml_ResourceDictionary_MergedDictionaries) in `App.xaml` to Merged your `ResourceDictionary` file

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```

**For more Info:** [ResourceDictionary and XAML resource references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#theme-resources-and-theme-dictionaries), [XAML for Windows 10 Controls - Styling](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-controls-14482?l=HXmdQWKtB_1604819052)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ResourceDictionary`, for example called "ThemeDictionary.xaml" and put the code you have for your `AcrylicBrush` in there.

Then in your `App.xaml` you can reference your `ResourceDictionary` like so:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemesDictionary.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```